# SSMS XEvent Profiler - how to access the data?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, extended-events

I have just updated my SSMS to v.17.3 and been pleased to see the new feature called [XEvent Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler). I wanted to ask is there any method to access the output of standard event using .xel file? Can we somehow target this session to write into it? Or is there any other smart method to access this in more RDBS style?

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions xs
JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets xst ON xst.[event_session_address] = xs.[address]
WHERE xs.[name] = N'QuickSessionStandard'
```

to find the location in `sys.dm_xe_session_targets.target_data`but without success.
This is just saying:

```
<LiveStreamTarget truncated="0">
    <clients>
        <client name="session_id=XX" pendingBuffers="0"></client>
    </clients>
</LiveStreamTarget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With focus on the Live Data window, click `Extended Events-->Stop Data Feed` on the menu. Then click `Extended Events-->Export to-->Table...` to save the captured trace data to a table, xel file, or CSV. These can be used for ad-hoc needs.

This feature is similar to the standard XE tools available when viewing session data under `Management-->Extended Events-->Sessions` except XE Profiler includes only pre-defined traces with live data rather than other targets.

Comment: Excellent! For .xel files I have created a sp reader and this is why I have never thought about checking whats behind the [Extended Events] button, now it looks even easier to use. Thanks for your time!